# VBA code to Split workbook into separate department reports

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and been to write a code so that a central log which records sales is split into separate workbooks based on department. I will need to run this on a weekly basis so need the code to overwrite the previous weeks report. If possible I need the new reports to have the same format as the central log so that they keep the same heading and cell formatting.

I haven't written any code as yet as it is way beyond my level

Comment: Welcome to S.O., the best approach would be to break down everything that needs to be done into basic tasks and tackle each task one at a time. There are lots of resources to learn VBA and probably lots of questions here that cover some of what you need to do. Once you have some code, if you hit a stumbling block, you can post it and we'll be happy to take a look and help out. As it is, your question is way too broad and is likely to be closed.

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Try this "Hello World" exercise for Excel VBA and tell us how you get on. https://davetallett26.github.io/SOExcelHW.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a similar question with an answer to get you started. The concept is the same as what you are looking to achieve and my response to this one has comments to help you track what is going on in the code. You will likely need to make some modifications to fit your file and setup but hopefully it helps you start the process of building out your own solution for your needs

[Split data into new workbooks based on data in a specific column, but exclude that specific column from the output files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117291/split-data-into-new-workbooks-based-on-data-in-a-specific-column-but-exclude-th/78118436#78118436)

Because you won't want to share any live data or files in the thread, you'll either need to show mockups of what the structure looks like so examples can be made specific to your case. But, even though you are new to VBA, if you can describe the process, you can definitely create the solution. Half the battle is just being able to articulate what you need the logic to do.